# Include or Remove decimal part in SSRS field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a numeric field in SSRS report. Currently, the properties of this field are set to show 2 decimal places.

I need to make a change to remove decimal points if the value is a whole number.

Ex: if the number is 12.31, the output on SSRS field should be 12.31

If the number is 12.00, the output on SSRS field should be 12

Can anyone please help how this can be done? Expressions or Field properties?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a SWITCH function on your data to get it into the preferred format.In the number section of the properties of your textbox (tablix cell etc)

[image: properties]

```
=switch( {your field}.value mod 1 = 0 , 0,
         {your field}.value mod 1 <> 0, 0.00)
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, formating codes should be quoted. Also when there is a single condition it's better use Iif for code readability. Switch is better than nesting Iif when there are more than one conditions.